# Where should I report wrong Unicode mappings?

Tags: fonts, unicode

I found an issue about mapping of Unicode characters ([clockwise](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/21bb/index.htm) and [anti-clockwise](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/21ba/index.htm) open circle arrow) in some fonts and already reported that to the unicode-math maintainer but I actually think, this is not the problem of the package.

Has there been some change in the Unicode numbering? Should I report that to the font maintainers or to Unicode?

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
Unicode Character ANTICLOCKWISE OPEN CIRCLE ARROW (U+21BA)

\verb+\acwopencirclearrow+

{\huge
\setmathfont{stixmath-regular.otf}
$\symbol{"021BA}$
\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}
$\symbol{"021BA}$
\setmathfont{asana-math.otf}
$\symbol{"021BA}$
\setmathfont{texgyretermes-math.otf}
$\color{red}\symbol{"021BA}$
\setmathfont{texgyrebonum-math.otf}
$\symbol{"021BA}$
\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}
$\color{red}\symbol{"021BA}$
\setmathfont{texgyreschola-math.otf}
$\symbol{"021BA}$
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}
$\color{red}\symbol{"021BA}$}

Unicode Character CLOCKWISE OPEN CIRCLE ARROW (U+21BB)

\verb+\cwopencirclearrow+

{\huge
\setmathfont{stixmath-regular.otf}
$\symbol{"021BB}$
\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}
$\symbol{"021BB}$
\setmathfont{asana-math.otf}
$\symbol{"021BB}$
\setmathfont{texgyretermes-math.otf}
$\color{red}\symbol{"021BB}$
\setmathfont{texgyrebonum-math.otf}
$\symbol{"021BB}$
\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}
$\color{red}\symbol{"021BB}$
\setmathfont{texgyreschola-math.otf}
$\symbol{"021BB}$
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}
$\color{red}\symbol{"021BB}$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Here http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tg-math/download/index_html#Termes_Math may be a good contact. As it is written, "Please note that the fonts may also be obtained from the Comprehensive Tex Archive Network or with the current TeX Live distribution, but bear in mind that this is the place to host their newest and shiniest versions."

Comment: unicode hasn't changed here you need to report it to the font maintainers. Tricky decision for the latex package maintainers whether to try to "fix" this by switching the mappings for the incorrect fonts trouble is then if the font is fixed the documents will "become wrong" as it's hard to reference a specific version of a font. A safer fix would be to make latex substitute a character from a correct font.

Comment: I once discovered a bug in one of the TeX Gyre fonts. I sent an email report about the issue to one of the GUST font maintainers, Bogusław Jackowski, and got a nice reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the friendly reply from GUST:

> this is what the developers have to say:
>
> It is a well-known -- needless to say, interim -- (mis)feature of
>   LM, TG Pagella and TG Termes. TG Bonum and TG Schola have the proper
>   slots. The issue will be corrected in the next release,    hopefully,
>   before long.
>
> so please be patient